# jQuery if element id exists add class to the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to addClass to an input if it exists and trigger a click else addClass to different element and trigger a click on it in jQuery but I am having some problems and tried different ways but with no luck. 
This is the html:

```
 <td>
     <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="free.free" id="free.free" />
     <label for="free.free">Free</label>
     <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="flat.flat" id="flat.flat" />
     <label for="flat.flat">Payed</label>
 </td>
```

and my script :

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('#free.free').length > 0) {
            $('#free.free').addClass('sgcheck');
            $('.sgcheck').trigger('click');
            }
        else { 
            $('#flat.flat').addClass('sgcheck');
            $('.sgcheck').trigger('click');
            }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you use ID's with periods in them ?

Comment: Because they are being generated by a foreach in php but I did not post the whole code.

Comment: Well change your foreach in PHP to generate normal ID's instead.

Comment: It's related to modifing two more modules and I do not have time to edit them. This is easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape dot character in id selector with double `\\`:

```
$('#free\\.free').length
```

otherwise `#free.free` selector means element with id `free` **and** class name `free`, which your HTML obviously doesn't have.

Comment: Wow... because of all the coding I did't check this one... I think it's time to stop for today... Thank  you very much :)